# clientY and clientX parameter of ngRightClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, right-click

I'm working on a list and i neet to open a little menu when clicking on the `<tr>`. I found some examples, e.g. [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/aFACA/) but this works with the left click...i want to intercept the right click. Since i'm working with Angular, i used the following directive:

```
app.directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
        element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
            });
        });
    };
});
```

i have decleared i div containing my menu:

```
<div id="mailingListMenuContainer" class="ms-core-menu-box ms-core-defaultFont ms-shadow">
    <ul class="ms-core-menu-list">
        <li text="Betrieb ausschließen" class="ms-core-menu-item ">
            <a class="ms-core-menu-link" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" title="Betrieb ausschließen">
                <div class="ms-hide"></div>
                <div class="ms-core-menu-label">
                    <span class="ms-core-menu-title">Betrieb ausschließen</span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="ms-accessible"></span>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the right click happens:

```
$scope.menuExclude = function($event){
    var container = $('#mailingListMenuContainer');
    container.css({
        top: $event.pageY + "px",
        left: $event.pageX + "px"
    });
    container.show();
};
```

The problem is that the page is big, and the menu appears above the tr... i found the same problem in [THIS](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Context-menu/) JQuery exmple. If you shrink the page in order that the scroll appeare, and you scroll to the bottom, you will see that the menu doesn't appear where it should.

I saw that the event parameter has the values `pageY` + `pageX` and `clientY` + `clientX`. What i don't understand, is why in my case `pageY` is always equal to `clientY` and `pageX` to `clientX`. Shouldn't they be different if the page is scrolled down?

Answer (score 0):

The most examples I've found don't work if there are a scrolled page... I used this algorythm in order to get the position:

```
var getOffsets = function($event){
    var p = {};
    var body = $event.target;
    p.x = body.offsetLeft;
    p.y = body.offsetTop;
    while (body.offsetParent) {
        p.x = p.x + body.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
        p.y = p.y + body.offsetParent.offsetTop;
        if (body == document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            body = body.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

However, after that you have to consider also other elements, im my case:

```
var GetExactClickPosition = function($event){

    var tr = $($event.target);
    if ($event.target.localName != 'tr'){
        tr = $($event.target).closest('tr');
    }

    var listDiv = $($event.target).closest('div');
    var p = getOffsets($event);
    var container = $('#mailingListExcludeMenuContainer');

    container.css({
        top: p.y - listDiv.scrollTop() - tr.height() - container.height() + $event.offsetY + "px",
        left: p.x + $event.offsetX + "px"
    });
    container.show();
};
```

I have a list with scroller inside the main scroller of the page...
I used it in order to show a little menu at the position of the mouse click.

Hope could be useful to someone...